# java, given a HashMap, how to organize HM numbers into a new array according to frequency(in hm)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, hashmap, numbers

given a HM that has key-number, value=amount of times repeated.

We sort by highest frequency to lowest frequency.
If two elements have same frequency, we sort by increasing value.

now I want to take this HM and sort it according to number frequency(how many times the same number is repeated) and place it inside a new array. here is the function I built(but doesn't work) how can I fix it and even make it more efficient?

```
public static void findMostFrequent(int[] ar,HashMap<Integer, Integer> t) {
    int frequency=ar[0],k=0;
    for(int i: t.keySet()) {
        for(int j: t.keySet()) { //string(word):all the values together
              if(t.get(j)> frequency) {
                frequency=t.get(j);
                for(int l=k;l<t.get(j);l++ ) {
                    ar[k]=frequency;
                    k++;
                }
                t.remove(frequency);
              }
              }
    }
}
```

example: given HM(hashmap) -`{2=1, 3=3, 5=2, 7=2, 9=1}`
I want the new array (called ar) to be: `(3,3,3,5,5,7,7,2,9)` basically the most frequent numbers first to the least frequent words, so if 3 was repeated 3 times and is the most repetitive number then in the new array (3,3,3) and etc...
help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use TreeMap<Integer, Integer>
2. make frequency as Key, so TreeMap keeps sorted order.
3. Iterate over Keyset and collect values.

if you don't have an option to use TreeMap. you can convert it to TreeMap inside your method.

here is an example:

```
public static void findMostFrequent(int[] ar, HashMap<Integer, Integer> t) {
        TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> sortedByVal = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

        int size=0;
        for (int key : t.keySet()) {
                int val = t.get(key);
                sortedByVal.putIfAbsent(val, new HashSet<>());

                Set<Integer> keys = sortedByVal.get(val);
                keys.add(key);
                sortedByVal.put(val, keys);
                size+=val;
            }

        ar = new int[size];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer key : sortedByVal.keySet()) {
            for (int val : sortedByVal.get(key)) {
               for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
                  ar[i++] = val;
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used this, but it put 0 in every part of the new array -ar- doesn't work

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
        ar[i++] = val;
}
forgot to iterate over key

Comment: did you add it?

Comment: yes, try now it should work. Tried to explain step-by-step. Actually, you can minimize the code but time complexity will be same

Comment: still doesn't work, still inserts zero each time, arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<3> but was:<0>

Comment: I'm getting this result when I ran:
[3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 9]

Comment: ok. just a little bug on seperate tests here. thanks

Comment: in addition how can i change/add to it If I sort if the wo elements have same frequency and sort by increasing value. @Zubaidullo Niimatullo uulu

Comment: here TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>, you can change to TreeSat, so it will become: TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> 

So if elements have same frequency, you'll have sorted elements by TreeSet

Answer (score 0):

A solution that comes in my mind is to first sort hashmap by values something like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = 
unsortedMap.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
(e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new))
```

then iterate the new linkedHashmap to make the result array.

Comment: thanks, but i don't know stream for java so this doesn't really help since I can't really understand whats happening in the code. thanks anyways